# Match marker colour with line colour in highcharter R

Tags: r, highcharts, r-highcharter

I'm creating a graph using the `highcharter` package in R:

[image: A line plot produced by highcharter in R of 5 sample countries with random values]

Each 'country' has a matched colour, which must stay consistent. How can I match marker colour with the line colour?

If it matters, sometimes not all countries will be displayed in the plot, but colours must consistently match their respective countries regardless.

Reproducible code:

```
library(highcharter)
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(110)

dat <- data.frame(
  Year = rep(2001:2021, 5),
  Country = rep(c("CountryA", "CountryB", "CountryC", "CountryD", "CountryE"), each = 21),
  Value = c(200, 150, 180, 220, 250, 400, 350, 300, 200, 250, 400, 550, 350, 300, 200, 250, 400, 300, 200, 250, 400,
            400, 250, 380, 120, 150, 200, 450, 500, 500, 650, 600, 650, 650, 600, 700, 750, 700, 700, 700, 750, 800,
            300, 250, 280, 520, 550, 500, 250, 400, 400, 350, 100, 450, 450, 500, 500, 550, 450, 550, 450, 450, 700,
            600, 750, 680, 620, 750, 600, 750, 600, 700, 850, 800, 850, 750, 800, 700, 850, 800, 800, 900, 750, 800,
            240, 450, 380, 320, 450, 300, 450, 300, 400, 550, 500, 550, 350, 500, 400, 350, 500, 450, 540, 250, 400
            )
) %>%
  mutate(
    Country_color = case_when(
      Country == "CountryA" ~ "#EA1102",
      Country == "CountryB" ~ "#123AAE",
      Country == "CountryC" ~ "#FF1EEA",
      Country == "CountryD" ~ "#661211",
      Country == "CountryE" ~ "#104E19"
    )
  )


dat %>% hchart(
  "line",
  hcaes(
    x = Year,
    y = Value,
    group = Country,
    color = Country_color
  )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

With little experience with `highcharter` myself, I think you could try `hc_colors()` instead of `color = Country_color`.

```
your_colors <- dat$Country_color %>% unique

dat %>% hchart(
    "line", 
    hcaes(
        x = Year,
        y = Value,
        group = Country)
    ) %>% 
    hc_colors(your_colors)
```

[image]